# GDB: debugging a child process after many fork()s

Tags: process, gdb, fork

I'm debugging a program which *repeats* the typical procedure of using `fork()` where the child process does some delegated task as the parent calls `waitpid()` to wait for the child to finish and then continues. For example:

```
while (!finished) {
    pid_t p = fork();
    if (p < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (p == 0) {
        /* Do something. For example: */
        if (/* some (rare) condition */) 
            raise(SIGSEGV);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else {
        int status;
        pid_t w = waitpid(p, &status, 0);
        if (w < 0) {
            perror("waitpid");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* Do something. */
    }
}
```

I'd like to run the program inside GDB and debug a child process that receives a signal, *no matter how many other child processes successfully finished and vanished before it*.

Of course, I need `set follow-fork-mode child`, because otherwise GDB won't look into the child processes. But this alone will detach the parent, lead GDB to the first child, and finish debugging upon its exit.

Therefore, I also need `set detach-on-fork off` to prevent the parent from being detached. However, this causes GDB to stop and give me a prompt, with the parent being suspended, when the first child exits. I could use `inferior` to choose the parent and issue `continue`, but *I need to do this for every child*. If the 1000th child is the one that receives the signal and that I want to look into, I need to repeat this process 999 times.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to, kind of, do this automatically and let GDB follow what the CPU would be executing, e.g. parent → child1 → parent → child2 → … , without stopping and prompting me, and stop at the first childN that receives a signal.

Comment: You might be able to script some of this with a GDB macro.  Alternatively, change your code so the 1000th (or whatever) child will dump core and then debug the core?

Answer (score 4):

If the signal you'd like to debug is `SIGSEGV` (or one of the other signals that causes the program to core dump), the easiest solution might be to just let the child dump core, and do post-mortem debugging.

Otherwise, you might want to catch the signal, print a message along the lines of `child 23435 caught signal 2; execute gdb /proc/23435 23435` and then suspend the child with e.g.

```
while(1) sleep(1);
```